# Using data context just as a object to execute my command in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I started my project using EF code-first. This is my `dbContext`:

```
 public class DataContext : DbContext
 {
        public DataContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
            this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

            Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<DataContext, MigrationsConfiguration>());
        }

        //CMSManagement
        public DbSet<News> News { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Page> Pages { get; set; }
        public DbSet<FileManagement> FileManagements { get; set; }
        //ClientProviderManagement
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
      ....
}
```

In the first month that I started my project i used this method to do my CRUD operations, as you can see :

```
public class LineRepository : ILineRepository
{
        private readonly DataContext _ctx;

        public LineRepository(DataContext ctx)
        {
            _ctx = ctx;
        }

        public bool Add(Line entity)
        {
            try
            {
                _ctx.Lines.Add(entity);
                _ctx.SaveChanges();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // TODO log this error
                return false;
            }
        }
}
```

But because of some reasons I had to use stored procedure as you can see :

```
public class InvoiceRepository : IInvoiceRepository
{
        public DataContext _ctx;

        public InvoiceRepository(DataContext ctx)
        {
            _ctx = ctx;
        }

        public bool Add(Invoice entity)
        {
            try
            {
                _ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"EXEC [dbo].[Billing.InsertInvoice]  

                @InvoiceDatetime,
                @OrganizationId,
                @SellerOrganizationId,
                @Serial,
                @SubmitDatetime", new SqlParameter("@InvoiceDatetime", entity.InvoiceDatetime),
                 new SqlParameter("@OrganizationId", entity.OrganizationId),
                 new SqlParameter("@SellerOrganizationId", entity.SellerOrganizationId),
                 new SqlParameter("@Serial", entity.Serial),
                 new SqlParameter("@SubmitDatetime", entity.SubmitDatetime));

                //_ctx.Invoices.Add(entity);
                //_ctx.SaveChanges();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // TODO log this error
                return false;
            }
}
```

As you can see in my second method I used `dbcontext` to execute my stored procedure. Butthe problem is the `Datasets` I mean here :

```
public DbSet<News> News { get; set; }
public DbSet<Page> Pages { get; set; }
public DbSet<FileManagement> FileManagements { get; set; }
//ClientProviderManagement
public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
```

I want to delete these datasets because I don't need them anymore. So when I remove this dataset, the table in database is removed too. How can I prevent to delete these tables?

My migrations function :

```
public class MigrationsConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<DataContext>
{
    public MigrationsConfiguration()
    {
        this.AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
        this.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: These `DbSet<T>` in your `DbContext` just represent the tables - if you have tables, you need to have these `DbSet<T>` member variables. Why do you want to remove those'? Doesn't make *any sense* at all!!

Comment: @marc_s i want to remove the dataset because i waste all my memory

Comment: @marc_s what about AutomaticMigrationsEnabled ?

Comment: I really doubt you can waste your memory by having properties. They don't contain all the data in your tables.

Comment: If you're going to use `EF` only to execute `SqlCommand`, you're probably better of using pure ADO.NET... Or use other micro ORM such as [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper)...